# Application Slowing down while filling up autocomplete drop down in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I am preparing an autocomplete drop down in angular 4. In the drop down I have to show options collected from various arrays. Since one among those array takes some time to fillup data I am using async method on it. After collecting all the arrays I concatenate all these arrays to one single array and made it an Observable. When I test my application it works perfectly but after using it sometime it gradually becomes slow. I am unable to figure out if there is any leaks going on or async-await mehtod is giving this probelm.

My main array where all the arrays are collected :

```
async  filterAllComponent(userinput){

        this.PlaceArray= await this.PlacesFilterAutocomplete(userinput);
        this.getTransporterArray= this.getfilterTransporter(userinput);
        this.getVehicleArray= this.getfilterVehicles(userinput);
        this.AllDropdownValues=this.getfilteredTransporter.concat(this.getVehicleArray);
        if(this.AllDropdownValues== undefined || typeof(this.AllDropdownValues) == 'object') {
          this.AllDropdownValuesOb= Observable.of([]);
        }    
        this.AllDropdownValuesOb= Observable.of(this.AllDropdownValues);
        console.log("all arrays",  this.AllDropdownValues)


      }
```

Now the async PlacesFilterAutocomplete array:

```
 async PlacesFilterAutocomplete(autocompleteInputData) {
    if (autocompleteInputData == '' || typeof(autocompleteInputData) == 'object') 
      return null;
    return this.placeData.getPlacesFromPig(autocompleteInputData)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => this.formatPigResponse(response));
  }
```

**Note:** this array " PlacesFilterAutocomplete " takes some time to fill so had to use promise.

Is this problem arising because of the async method or some garbage on the array. I am unable to find. I am not writing the other arrays because even if I am using only PlacesFilterAutocomplete, removing the other arrays,  this problme still exist.

Edit: adding the HTML part :

```
 <mat-autocomplete #mainAutocomplete="matAutocomplete" #transporterSearch="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayOptionsFields">
            <mat-option
            *ngFor="let value of AllDropdownValuesOb | async" [value]="value" (onSelectionChange)="OptionSelected($event)">
                <mat-icon style="font-size:1em" *ngIf="value.type=='PlaceType'">location_on</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon style="font-size:1em" *ngIf="value.type=='VehicleType'">local_shipping</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon style="font-size:1em" *ngIf="value.type=='TransporterType'">person_pin</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon style="font-size:1em" *ngIf="value.type=='DateType'">person_pin</mat-icon>
                {{ value.value}}
                <mat-icon *ngIf="offlinePlaces" style="font-size:1em; float:right; padding-top:0.6em; color:red;">cloud_off</mat-icon>
            </mat-option>
            <!--transporter-->
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: _Note: this array " PlacesFilterAutocomplete " takes some time to fill so had to use promise._ Not quite sure what you mean by that. Observables are literally made for async operations.

Comment: Do you use multiple autocompletes?

Comment: No I have to use single autocomplete to display all the data collected from different array. @Swoox

Comment: @Shadowlauch actually if I don't use promise than the final array is constructed even before the PlacesFilterAutocomplete is completrely filled up. So  Autocomplete dont show values of PlacesFilterAutocomplete. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you also add your HTML  part?

Comment: It's interesting how you re subscribing on this observable

Comment: @EvgeniyMalyutin  I have added the html part responsible for the Autocomplete

Comment: Also can you confirm that formatPigResponce does not produce any side effects?

Comment: format response is just a function to convert the API response in appropriate object so that It can be rendered properly.